# How do I process the data from a form in a server (node js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a website, with a section that allows a user to log in. 
Once the user has entered their details and clicked "log in", how would I get that information from the server request to process? I am aware of the "get" method, however, whenever I use this, all of the values from the form are displayed in the URL (including the password).

Here is the function from the server file that deals with the request

```
function handle(request, response) {
  var url = request.url;
  url = removeQuery(url);
  url = lower(url);
  url = addIndex(url);

  var querystring = require('querystring');
  var params = querystring.parse(require('url').parse(request.url).query);

  if (! valid(url)) return fail(response, NotFound, "Invalid URL");
  if (! safe(url)) return fail(response, NotFound, "Unsafe URL");
  if (! open(url)) return fail(response, NotFound, "URL has been banned");

  var type = findType(url);
  if (type == null) return fail(response, BadType, "File type unsupported");
  if (type == "text/html") type = negotiate(request.headers.accept);
  reply(response, url, type);
}
```

Basically, how can I get the information out of a form without it being visible in the URL?

Comment: The browser has to make a POST request. `request` should have a method to get the *body* of the request which you can parse.

Comment: Thanks. What method would I use to get the body of a request?

Answer (score 2):

First stop: change `<form action="..." ...` to `<form method="POST" action="..." ...` so the browser will send the form data in a POST.

Next up, `request.body` has the information you're looking for, though it's not a string, it's a stream, so it's a bit hard to look at.  Look at [express](http://expressjs.com) as a higher-level tool that'll parse these things for you.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into express. I had seen the "post" method mentioned, however I didn't fully understand how I could extract the information I was after

Comment: Take a look at the F12 developer tools (e.g. push F12 in your browser) to see the request / response your browser sends.  If you're on Windows, Fiddler is a great tool to see it too.